# Amazon SQS Python/boto: how do I send messages with accented characters?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to send this string on Python SQS:
"Talhão", with no quotes.

How do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

install the newest version of boto (2.27 or more, lower versions have an issue with unicode strings)
send it as unicode, and you will succeed